# Any work around for iCloud bug getting the Content Changed Date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icloud

Has anybody has a work around for the bug in iCloud that returns the creation date of an iCloud file instead of the modification date when calling `NSMetadataItemFSContentChangeDateKeyon` on a `NSMetadataItem`. When calling `NSMetadataItemFSCreationDateKey` returns a `nil`.

Comment: if anybody has found a way to find the modification date of an iCloud file, or has found an alternative way to deal with this problem

Comment: Can you give a code fragment that shows the problem? Also can you provide a link to the bug report (since this is apparently a known problem)? With those the question is a lot more likely to be recognizable for future visitors (and will probably get more serious attention from potential answerers too).